# Angular 1 watching a inner keyvalue of an array of element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make a responsive fixed table header. The table header will be out of flow with the table; therefore, I have queried the original table headers and created array of elements that I want to watch the inner width of all of them.

**Caveat:** I know this is quick and dirty and not angular way, please bear with me.

**Question:**
How can I watch all the index's of `listItemHooks[i]` not just `[0]` index?

```
var listItemHooks = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.language-header-list-items-hook'));
  $scope.$watch(function(){
    return listItemHooks[0].clientWidth
  }, function(o,v){
    console.log(o,v);
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the following?

```
$scope.$watchCollection(function () {
    return [].slice.call(listItemHooks).map(function (listItem) {
        return listItem.clientWidth;
    });
}, function (newWidths, oldWidths) {
    // Do something
});
```

The watcher will be invoked when at least one of the widths changes (followed by a scope digest, of course).

Comment: So angular.element() returns an object not an array :( is there an equivalent to map?

Comment: Thanks for this. Super elegant.

Answer (score 0):

What you're $watching has to be on the $scope and then you need to do a deep $watch.

```
$scope.listItemHooks = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.language-header-list-items-hook'));

$scope.$watch('listItemHooks', function(o,v){
  console.log(o,v);
}, true);
```

The `true` as the last argument in the `$watch` function makes it check object equality, and it gets expensive. You could also look at `$watchCollection`, which I don't think works here, but is good to know about.

Comment: Thanks for effort!  I suggest you look at gustavohenke answer it's elegant!

Comment: thanks! yep, his answer is good, $watchCollection is definitely better than a deep $watch.